# What is the name for the section of vertical tiling underneath a bay window?

Tags: windows, roof, tiling

[image: 1930s house England]

As per the highlighted section in this picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As odd as it may seem, it's a roof. A bay window roof. In the picture you provide, it's actually a roof for the lower bay window, as opposed to being part of the upper bay window.

Comment: That is a lot more logical, thanks. Obviously the lower section needs to exist first, hence roof is less odd than my upside-down point of view!